ARIMA model underestimates
What steps should we take if my ARIMAX model consistently underestimates?
Furthermore, should this underestimation be a significant concern in my analysis?
Edit:
I am doing an ARIMAX forecast where I use sentiment from news papers as my exogenous variable to predict stock movement, and compare error metrics + Diebold-Mariano to that of a Random Walk.
This means i have missing values in weekend and holidays.
My forecasted values in my ARIMAX is underestimating that of the actual movement.
The ARIMAX model passes skewness, and serial-correlation, and has no issues with such.
Code:
library(forecast)

set.seed(123) # Setting Seed

# Split, train and Test.
split_index <- round(0.8 * nrow(fin_zoo2))
train_data <- fin_zoo2[1:split_index, ]
test_data <- fin_zoo2[(split_index + 1):nrow(fin_zoo2), ]

# Column Names
colnames(train_data)[which(colnames(train_data) == "FINsentiment2")] <- "FINsentiment2"
colnames(test_data)[which(colnames(test_data) == "FINsentiment2")] <- "FINsentiment2"

train_data_core <- coredata(train_data)
test_data_core <- coredata(test_data)

# Standard Deviation
error_sd <- sd(diff(train_data_core[, "OMXdaily_return2"]))

# Metrics accumulation vectors
metrics_accumulator <- list(
  RW_MAPE = numeric(50), ARIMAX_MAPE = numeric(50),
  RW_MedAE = numeric(50), ARIMAX_MedAE = numeric(50),
  RW_sMAPE = numeric(50), ARIMAX_sMAPE = numeric(50),
  RW_RMSE = numeric(50), ARIMAX_RMSE = numeric(50) 
)

for(trial in 1:50) {
    set.seed(123 + trial) # Seed
    
    random_walk_forecasts <- numeric(nrow(test_data_core))
    arimax_forecasts <- numeric(nrow(test_data_core))
    
    for(i in 1:nrow(test_data_core)) {
        current_train_data <- fin_zoo2[1:(split_index + i - 1), ]
        current_train_data_core <- coredata(current_train_data)
        
        # Update standard deviation based on all available data up to this point
        updated_error_sd <- sd(diff(current_train_data_core[, "OMXdaily_return2"]))
        
        error_term <- rnorm(1, mean = 0, sd = updated_error_sd)
        last_observation <- tail(current_train_data_core[, "OMXdaily_return2"], 1)
        random_walk_forecasts[i] <- last_observation
        
        if(i > 1) { 
            xreg_train <- as.matrix(current_train_data_core[, "FINsentiment2", drop = FALSE])
            xreg_forecast <- test_data_core[i - 1, "FINsentiment2", drop = FALSE]
            arima_model_with_exog <- Arima(current_train_data_core[, "OMXdaily_return2"], 
                                           xreg = xreg_train, 
                                           order = c(2, 0, 2), 
                                           include.mean = FALSE)
            arimax_forecasts[i] <- forecast(arima_model_with_exog, xreg = xreg_forecast, h = 1)$mean
        }
    }
    
 #Metrics calculations   
    
    actual_values <- test_data_core[, "OMXdaily_return2"]
    metrics_accumulator$RW_MAPE[trial] <- mean(abs((actual_values - random_walk_forecasts) / actual_values)) * 100
metrics_accumulator$ARIMAX_MAPE[trial] <- mean(abs((actual_values - arimax_forecasts) / actual_values)) * 100
    metrics_accumulator$RW_MedAE[trial] <- median(abs(actual_values - random_walk_forecasts))
metrics_accumulator$ARIMAX_MedAE[trial] <- median(abs(actual_values - arimax_forecasts))
    metrics_accumulator$RW_sMAPE[trial] <- mean(2 * abs(actual_values - random_walk_forecasts) / (abs(actual_values) + abs(random_walk_forecasts))) * 100
metrics_accumulator$ARIMAX_sMAPE[trial] <- mean(2 * abs(actual_values - arimax_forecasts) / (abs(actual_values) + abs(arimax_forecasts))) * 100
    # RMSE calculations
    metrics_accumulator$RW_RMSE[trial] <- sqrt(mean((actual_values - random_walk_forecasts)^2))
metrics_accumulator$ARIMAX_RMSE[trial] <- sqrt(mean((actual_values - arimax_forecasts)^2))
}

# Calculate mean metrics
final_metrics <- sapply(metrics_accumulator, mean)

# Final table
final_metrics_table <- data.frame(
  Metric = c("MAPE", "MedAE", "sMAPE", "RMSE"),
  Random_Walk = final_metrics[c("RW_MAPE", "RW_MedAE", "RW_sMAPE", "RW_RMSE")],
  ARIMAX = final_metrics[c("ARIMAX_MAPE", "ARIMAX_MedAE", "ARIMAX_sMAPE", "ARIMAX_RMSE")]
)
print(final_metrics_table)


You should give more informations on the analysis you're doing. Many reasons can explain an underestimation: data quality, your model parameters, lack of modalities/variables. Did you perform a cross-validation ? Check the residuals ?

More information is needed indeed as @p1char said. One reason might be that your noise is not normally distributed. E.g. you are trying to predict a value that cannot exceed some maximum or minimum.

The model has normally distributed residuals and has no issues with serial correlation either

What if you substitute real data with simulated data? Do you still get the same problem?

How would one create a simulated dataset? And what can i conclude from this?

You generate normally distributed random variables, correlate them as per your ARIMA params. What you conclude from this is whether your model for data generation fits your observations. If it does not, you need to fix it. Here we are talking about randomly generated data fitting your training data, not the test data

Also you can then try to put the simulated data back into ARIMA fitter to check whether your inference algorithm can recover the simulation params. Word of caution though, you can get different but equally likely solutions
